Autofill Destination - How to Account for Increase to the Range as Report Grows with Time
I'm working on a macro that takes a large general ledger report, that includes Project ID#s that I'm not interested in, filters out the unwanted projects and then does some formatting to get the wanted data into a more usable state.
Range("A10").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Columns("D:D").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Range("D10").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Match to DESIRED PROJECT List"
Range("D11").Select
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-10
Range("D11").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=INDEX(LIST!C[-3],MATCH(RC[-1],LIST!C[-3],0))"
Range("D11").Select
Selection.AutoFill **Destination:=Range("D11:D83409")**
Range("D11:D83409").Select
ActiveSheet.**Range("$A$10:$AX$83409")**.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="#N/A"
Rows("11:11").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
ActiveSheet.Range**("$A$10:$AX$5472"**).AutoFilter Field:=4
Range("A10").Select

I recorded a macro and have it working as I want, but my concern is for next month, when the data has more rows, how do I get the bolded sections of my code above to update to the larger row numbers - without having to tweak the code manually each time? Essentially, I want the first bold spot to be D11:DLastRowWithData
Point me in the right direction if this has already been solved - I briefly searched for similar problems but figured this would be quicker.
Thanks in advance for any help with this!
I have not really tried anything yet... my first thought would be to use "D:D" and fill in the entire column, but that seems like it would slow the workbook down by running my indexMatch formula for every row - plus the starting point of my report is a formatted report that starts on row 10 (headers), so D:D would include some rows above the report - but I'm trying to be forward thinking about when my data grows - I'd like to avoid having to update my code for number or rows each month, especially considering that I'll likely be sharing this macro with other users who are far less comfortable stepping into VBA and making changes.

Something like Dim lastRow As Long, With ActiveSheet, lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row, .Range("D11:D" & lastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=INDEX(LIST!C[-3],MATCH(RC[-1],LIST!C[-3],0))", End With. I assumed you'd use column A to find the last row.
